# Beacon-chain fault tolerant load balancing

Tags: beacon-chain

I use [dshackle](https://github.com/emeraldpay/dshackle) to load balance incoming RPC requests for ETH1. Recently, I tried to look for the same solution on ETH2/beacon-chain, and I found an old repo that service doesn't work correctly when I deploy it.

It's possible to do so using general web load balancers like Nginx or HAProxy, but we have to use a single client (lighthouse, prysm, etc) due to different implementations of beacon-chain clients.

PS: Round-robin DNS is not that intelligent and useful.